# Logging in common artifact

Tags: java, log4j

I am creating a common artifact that can be imported into different projects in my company. I have some debug logging statements (log4j) in my code.

My question is whether I should include a log4j dtd and xml in my jar, and what setting I need to have in the xml? I want the debug messages to be displayed only if the parent project enabled debug level, and the messages should go into the log file configured in that project.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a wrapper like [Simple Logging Facade for Java](http://www.slf4j.org/) or [Commons Logging](http://commons.apache.org/logging/) in my artifact and let the integrator decide which logging tool to use and how to configure it.

Comment: I vote slf4j, possibly with [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) as default, replaceable implementation, should you feel the need to provide one.